# How to get the checkout page register Entered value in core file

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer, customer-session

I need the value enter the checkout page customer register form entering value in **app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php** file. IS possible to get the entering value .

Answer (score 0):

you can get **checkout post values** of billing using following code

```
$billing=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing');
echo $billing['city'];
echo $billing['postcode'];
```

Comment: $billing['vat_id'] is not working. @Qaisar Satti

Comment: @Crock can you share the generated html of that field

Comment: Actually., I need to remove the tax applying when customer enter the vat id.

so I went **app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php** 
function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
inside i write
$billing=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing');
  $quote = $billing['vat_id'];
  if($quote !="")
  {
   return 0;
  }

Comment: @Crock i know but what is your filed code did you added custom field you must be enter with field  `name=billing['vat_id'];` then you can get it by this code

Comment: **<input id="billing:taxvat" name="billing[taxvat]" value="" title="Belasting/VAT nummer" class="input-text validation-passed" type="text">**

Comment: or we need to get like this billing['taxvat']; ?

Comment: @Crock try with  `echo $billing['taxvat'];` because your filed name is `taxvat`

Comment: Getting same. issue not return 0 **$quote = $billing['taxvat']; if($quote !="") { return 0; }**

Comment: @Crock you can check the values of your field. and check with `return 0;` without any check so you can see it is working on not

Comment: Default i return 0 inside the function. Tax return 0. i have checked, now i need to check whether billing taxvat is empty or not.

Comment: @did you check the value's `$billing=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing'); print_r($billing);` you can check your values is their or not and try to delete `var/cache` folder too

Comment: Can you give a advise for me. Can i print inside the function print_r($billing);

Comment: @Crock yes you can do anything and check the output in console or use magneto log for that